# Error: type namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist - Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm trying to get into Visual Studio for Mac but I can't even get the Hello World application to run without issue. This is what the program looks like:

[image]

This is the errors I keep getting.

[image]

I'm not sure what the issue is. I thought maybe I didn't actually have .Net installed so I installed it but that didn't help. Any help trying to diagnose this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is a console app you shouldn't have a Startup.cs with ASP.NET stuff in it. Did you create a proper project?

Comment: You're right, I followed the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/using-on-mac-vs      and there all that was created was a program.cs file, I don't know why I have two. But it's a .NET Core console application